# Ubuntu to Windows openoffice save issues?

Tags: windows-7, linux, openoffice

I just finished working on my teacher's paper, which is due to her an hour ago... For 2 hours I've been trying to find my paper anywhere on ubuntu, or my windows installation. It is nowhere, anymore. The paper took me 4 hours to type up, and I JUST saved it onto my windows installation. The desktop of my user profile, to be exact. I restarted to windows to print it off, but it wasn't on my desktop. First reaction: FFUUU, wait backup. SO I went to my backup directory of linux. Guess what: Nothing there.... Any way of gettin my work back without retyping all 8 pages?

Comment: It's not in your recent documents in the file/recent documents in OpenOffice?

Comment: It is, which is strange. It says file can not be found, and yes, I do have the partition mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue results to be:
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=95431#p546105

Never heard of the such.

Answer (score 0):

can you force a checkdisk to run? its possible that Linux did not properly finish writing it to the NTFS file system.

Comment: Yeah.  I can do that, but if I am not mistaken, running a checkdisk will make it to where data save programs might not pick up an incomplete data write.